# Testing Model with Observer in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm trying to test a controller which creates a model.

There is an observer that listens the `created` event on the model. The observer is responsible to dispatch jobs to create sub-models(table entries) that depend on the base model/table.

I know that `I'm sure it will work` is the worst thing to say while testing. To be able to test the functionality of the whole process I add something like ;

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
    TariffPricingComponentsCalculater::dispatchNow($tariff, $components);
}
```

I have the feeling that this piece of code should not be in the prod version. Is there a cleaner way to dispatch the job immediately while testing

Thank you.

Comment: you could let the code work as needed by creating a model and letting the observer fire off the jobs ... you can fake the queue so it won't actually dispatch but you will be able to assert that things were queued

Comment: I see,  that means I have to test the job in a different test file to be sure that it does the thing I expect from it. Am I right ?

Comment: kinda depends what you are doing and how this is setup but you do have the facilities to be able to test a lot of things by faking a lot of services, obviously how you have also designed your code also comes into play with how easy it will be or not to test in isolation

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is working now with two separated test files and a faked queue :)

Answer (score 1):

The better approach to disable observers while testing would be calling `Model::unsetEventDispatcher()` in setup method.

For example: Here I have `Plan` model which has an observer called `PlanObserver` and I can disable them in `setup` method of test class by:

```php
class PlanTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp():void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        
        Plan::unsetEventDispatcher();
    }
}
```